# How to factor a vector (times it by itself a set number of times)?

Tags: python, vector

How do I factor a vector, so take a vector and multiply by itself a number of times. I tried `vec=vector**4` but get:

> Runtime error (TypeErrorException): unsupported operand type(s) for **: 'Vector3d' and 'int'

Comment: First, that's not what "factoring" means. What you want is "exponentiation".

Comment: Second, the problem is obviously that whatever `Vector3d` class you're using, it doesn't support the `**` operator. If you wrote that class yourself, show us the code, and we can show you how to add support for it (or just look up `__pow__` in the data model section of the docs). If you're using some third-party library, tell us what library, and maybe we can tell you what it supports if you can't find it in the docs yourself.

Comment: I am working with Rhino3d rhinoscriptsyntax... I will research exponentiation . thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Vector3d` is a type you designed yourself, you need to add support for `**` explicitly.

If you look at the documentation for [Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types), you'll see that the method you need to write is:

```
object.__pow__(self, other[, modulo])
```

If you're confused by that third argument, `__pow__` is used not only for the `**` operator, but also for the [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) function, which takes an optional third argument for modular exponentiation. If you don't want to support that, you can ignore it.

Now, how do you implement vector exponentiation? Well, if you only care about whole number powers, you can always do it through repeated cross-product. Assuming you've defined the `*` operator to mean cross-product:

```
class Vector3d(object):
    # ... other methods ...
    def __pow__(self, power):
        if not isinstance(power, numbers.Integral) or other < 0:
            # give power.__rpow__ a chance, just in case...
            return NotImplemented
        result = type(self)(1, 1, 1)
        for _ in range(power):
            result *= self
        return result
```

If you want to be able to raise vectors to real, complex, or vector powers, then there are a few different ways to define those things, and if you don't know which one you want, you probably need to ask about it on Math rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: wow. thanks for this in depth reply! I will study all these super helpful answers carefully! so much to learn!!!